# How to convert a string to an image to make a single executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I created a simple program that creates a window with tkinter. I converted the background image of the canvas into a string so that I can compile it with the main program to create a single executable file.

I used the following code to make the conversion from image to text:

```
import base64

with open("background.png", "rb") as imageFile:
    str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
text_file = open("background.txt", "wb")
text_file.write(str)
text_file.close()
```

The problem now is that I can't figure out how to convert the text file back into an image. This the reduced version of my simple window program. I am using Python 3.4 and have imported `io` and tried using `io.StringIO` to no avail.

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import io 

...other stuff

backgroundImage=root.PhotoImage(io.StringIO('background.txt')) # This line is my problem
backgroundLabel=root.Label(parent,image=backgroundImage)

...more stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to have the actual base64 encoded graphic as part of your `.py` file?  Then you'll need to manually copy the contents of `background.txt` into your `.py` file... something like this:

```
background_image = """\
019248a8b2f129d    # obviously not real data  ;)
c12e0284a8172f0
""".strip()
```

and then have something like:

```
# untested
backgroundImage = root.PhotoImage(io.StringIO(base64.decode(background_image)))
...
```

Comment: I think it would be more convenient to have the base64 encoded graphic as part of a separate `.py` file, to keep the code organized. Can I set `background_image` equal to a string from another `.py` file?

Comment: @user4261180: Sure can -- import the other file, then reference the string: `import images` ... `...base64.decode(images.background)...`

Comment: Thanks, i didn't think of that. A module is in fact just a script. But how does the program know the file path of the string file if it is not a module?